# how do i make diffrent registration form in drupal?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-forms

Is there a module that can make different registration forms for different roles during sign up? (ex. each Editor,Main User,Sub User role have different form)

Comment: And how do you know what role the user will have before s/he signs up?

Comment: with url(ex. reg/editor, reg/main ,reg/sub)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is :)

http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole

to assign by path you will also need Content Profile:

http://drupal.org/project/content_profile

check out this tutorial on how to pull it off:

http://www.web-a-team.com/blog-post/user-registration-more-one-role

Comment: i installed this,but how create different page?with different Profile fields?

Comment: [here is a mini-tutorial that should explain it](http://www.web-a-team.com/blog-post/user-registration-more-one-role), I've also edited my answer to reflect the second module needed

Comment: tnx,but my problem not solved.i want for example in page "reg/main" user have "Father Name" filed,but in "reg/sub" user have "Brother Name" field!

Comment: That's meant to be one of the main reasons to use the solution I've suggested, have you tried adding a new field to your new content profiles?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you should do

1. start with install profile2-7.x-1.2.tar.gz.
2. entity-7.x-1.0-rc3.tar.gz  once you have profile2 installed -->
3. enable --> click on configure - (Here you see your profile types
   -add as many as you want).

when you add a new one or modify the existing one "Main" make sure you check "Provide a separate page for editing profiles."
 4. Now to have different registration, login and password change pages 
install and enable profile2_regpath-7.x-1.9.tar.gz
Now visit the profile Types Page again here you should see "UNIQUE REGISTRATION PATH" .. rest is easy ..

Comment: @MJH you can add fields you need to Profile Type, exactly same fields would appear on the registration form & profile view form for specific profile type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some idea how to solve your question in drupal 7(I think it should work in drupal 6 also). However its not safe since anyone can just change the role they have:

```
function my_module_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    $company_role = $form_state['build_info']['args'][0];

    $form['account']['company_role'] = array(
        '#type'         => 'select',
        '#title'        => t('Company role'),
        '#options'      => drupal_map_assoc(array('editor','main user','Sub User')),
        '#description'  => t('Please select your company role'),
        "#empty_option" =>t('- Select -'),
        '#weight'       => -11,  // Add the select box above username that have weight -10

    );

    switch (strtolower($company_role)) {
        case 'editor':
            // add extra fields for editor
            $form['account']['company_role']['#default_value'] = $company_role;
            break;
        case 'main user':
            // add extra fields for main
            $form['account']['company_role']['#default_value'] = $company_role;
        case 'sub user';
            // add extra fields for 'Sub User'
            $form['account']['company_role']['#default_value'] = $company_role;
            break;
        default:
            $form['account']['company_role']['#empty_option'] = t('- Select -');
            $company_role = null;// error handling or default case
    }

}
```

If you for example have LDAP in your company you could instead get this information from LDAP(https://www.drupal.org/node/1053748). Then you can be more sure about the role is chosen correctly.