# Different registration forms for different types of users

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

This is my first time building a site with Drupal (7).  I have plenty experience with LAMP, HTML/CSS and javascript, but I want to make sure I am doing things the 'Drupal way' before I start hacking together a custom solution unnecessarily.  I've searched forums and modules, but have come up empty.

The site I am building will have different tiers of users: students, teachers, and parents.  The difference between these users is:

1. The information collected during registration, and
2. The pages the user's have access to.

I think at least part of the solution lies with creating roles for each type of user, but it seems Drupal only has one registration page for all users.  How would I create a different registration form for each type of user?  What is the 'usual' way of assigning roles to users automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is late the game here but I thought I might refer people to the "Rules" module... Instead of thinking about this from the "user-specific" registration form perspective, think of it instead from the perspective that you still have only 1 form but with additional / optional inputs, whereby subsequent actions (rules) are then enacted upon depending on the values of said additional / optional fields.

You might also check this out, too:
[how do i make diffrent registration form in drupal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992992/how-do-i-make-diffrent-registration-form-in-drupal)

Answer (score 0):

I'm just updating my answer as I see it didn't apply for D7.

I've just begun developing a D7 site with a similar request.
There seems to be a module which should fit perfectly, although I still have to try it:
http://drupal.org/project/profile2

Good luck with it.

Comment: To separate different user roles with unique forms you are able to use this module (profile2) with additional one called Profile2 Registration Path [link]http://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath